# grub cannot see a disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 preinstalled on a Dell laptop. I tried to add a second linux and configure GRUB to boot it. So, I edited /etc/grub.d/40_custom and added the following lines:

```
menuentry 'New_linux 4.4.26 na /dev/sda8' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos8'
                linux /boot/linux-x86_64-4.4.26 root=/dev/sda8 ro
                initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-x86_64-4.4.26
        }
```

But as a result Grub is complaining that it cannot find the disk. These things related to Grub are getting more and more complicated and I cannot find any comprehensive manual explaining how to do even such a basic and simple thing as boot a second linux system. Any ideas or guidance from your side? I will be more than grateful.

Comment: When installing the second one just make sure to NOT to install Grub as well. Then, after rebooting into the first one, run `sudo update-grub` so the second is detected and added to the Grub menu. It's that simple!

Comment: I did not install second Grub.  Of course I run update-grub. It was updated Grub that was complaining about not finding a disk.